# How to create a Listview within a Listview using an external xml file from url

Tags: android, xml, listview, xml-parsing, listactivity

Currently I have done my CustomizedListViewActivity using a xml file from the url to get my datas. However I have a problem trying to link the item that i am suppose to click to another `ListView`.
What I want is :

**CustomizedListActivity :**
- A
- B
- C

When click on A will give:

**ListViewA:**
-1
-2
-3

When click on B will give:

**ListViewB:**
-4
-5
-6

When click on C will give:

**ListViewC:**
-7
-8
-9

Comment: you are not supposed to put a listview in a listview. what you are looking for is expandablelistview

Comment: Use `ExpandableListView`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the expandable ListView

Take a look here

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

OR

http://android-adda.blogspot.in/2011/06/custom-expandable-listview.html

This may help you.

Comment: Thanks it's useful... However I have a small question...if my listview is customized will it affect my layout...?